# Let section start at a specific page

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, blank-page, page

I am typesetting a document with a multiple-page TOC. Problem is, the TOC is cleared any time a compiling begins but does not successfully finish -- which happens quite frequently.

Because my TOC has more than one page, practically any imperfect compiling upsets the current PDF page location and I would *have* to compile again successfully.

So, is there a way to specify that a section must start at a certain page in the PDF document, and leave there any number of blank pages to fill the page count?

Comment: You could leave out the ToC while editing the document and put it back later. That way saves you from the hassle to get the right pages and also saves some time.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed page number should help. Unfortunately you did not provide a MWE that demonstrates the problem with your toc to test the following code.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{2}

\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am quite sure this isn't what the OP is looking for.